# Auto-layout constraints not working as expected

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I've got a UITableViewCell that has a child view, and within it an image view and a label. I am wanting to use the child view as a means of giving some margin around the contents of the cell, thus giving me margins inbetween cells. This seemed to be the way a lot of people online recommended doing it.

I've set up my constraints as shown below:

[image]

I have performed a *Update Frames* on all views in the view controller. The story board shows it exactly as I'm expecting it to be on the phone. When I run it on the phone though, I get this...

[image]

I'm completely baffled at this point. I've spent two days of reading and trying to layout a simple UITableViewCell and clearly don't have a good understanding of how auto-layout works still.

I've even just laid everything out along the suggested boundaries (the blue lines) and then told the storyboard to generate suggested constraints. At which point the content of the cell just sent with 50% of it off the right side of the screen and un-viewable.

So two questions:

The storyboard more often than not shows me something that is not accurately represented on my actual device. Is this fairly common in iOS development? Should I not be relying at all on the storyboard auto-layout representation?

What do I have to do to these constraints in order to get the cells to layout on my device, like it is shown in my storyboard at this time? What constraints am I setting wrong?

Comment: I don't think your problem is in the Table Cells, they look OK, I think the problem is in the TableView itself.  It looks like you have made it constrained to the edges of the 600 size storyboard.

Comment: Should I not constrain it to the edges?

Comment: Yes, you should, but you don't want it to be 600 wide all the time which is what it looks like is happening.  I am not sure what your constraints are, but if you have a fixed width constraint, that could cause the problem you are seeing.

Comment: I don't believe I have a fixed width on the table view. I wanted, for the time being, the UiTableView to be the full width on all devices. So I constrained to the leading and trailing edges. I'll try removing those constraints and see how it works

Answer (score 1):

Storyboard doesn't display the content according to any device by default. You can set it to your current device in its size properties(by default it is "Inferred"). Constraints are used to display the views equal on all devices. They automatically adjust UIelements according to display size. So if you want your app to run on devices of different sizes you have to rely on constraints.

I think you are setting too many constraints. Happens if you are new to auto layout. Try reading [this](https://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.captechconsulting.com%2Fblogs%2Fios-7-tutorial-series-auto-layout-in-xcode-5&h=yAQEKMtjR) guide. Its very helpful.